# ESP32 - resetting BT(classic)-Discovery variables ends in memory chaos

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, bluetooth

I want to search for bt devices in each loop(), store them and query them one by one. This works fine so far. However, when I try to reset the corresponding variables, **I get the following error: "Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled."**

This is to ensure that new devices are found rather than iterating over old (no longer existing) devices.

```
// BT
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"
BluetoothSerial SerialBT;
#define BT_DISCOVER_TIME 10000 

//BT_DEVICES
BTScanResults* pScanResults;
String** deviceNames;
int numDevices;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //BT
  SerialBT.begin(DEVICE_NAME, true); // device is master
}

void loop() {
  btDiscover();
  requestData();
}

void btDiscover() {
  pScanResults = SerialBT.discover(BT_DISCOVER_TIME);
  
  if (pScanResults != nullptr && pScanResults->getCount() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pScanResults->getCount(); i++) {
      BTAdvertisedDevice* pDevice = pScanResults->getDevice(i);
      if (pDevice != nullptr) {
        String deviceName = pDevice->getName().c_str();
        if (deviceName.startsWith(SLAVE_NAME_PATTERN)) {
          addDeviceName(deviceName.c_str());
        }
      }
    }
  }
  SerialBT.discoverClear();

}

bool deviceNameExists(const String& name) {
  for (int i = 0; i < numDevices; i++) {
    if (deviceNames[i]->equals(name)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

void addDeviceName(const String& name) {
  if (!deviceNameExists(name)) {
    deviceNames = (String**)realloc(deviceNames, (numDevices + 1) * sizeof(String*));
    deviceNames[numDevices] = new String(name);
    numDevices++;
  }
}
void requestData() {
  for (int i = 0; i < numDevices; i++) {
    SerialBT.connect(*deviceNames[i]);
    SerialBT.println("REQUEST");
    delay(100);
    String message = SerialBT.readStringUntil('\n');

    StaticJsonDocument<200> jsonDocument;
    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(jsonDocument, message);
    if (error == DeserializationError::Ok) {
      serializeJson(jsonDocument, Serial); 
      Serial.println(); 
    } else {
      // Fehler beim Parsen der JSON-Nachricht
      Serial.println("ERROR");
    }
    SerialBT.disconnect();
  }
}
```

i tried something similar to this:

```
delete pScanResults;
    pScanResults = nullptr;
  }

  delete[] deviceNames;
  deviceNames = nullptr;
  numDevices = 0;
```

how can i realize this? i tried vectors instead of String**, but that triggered the problem instantaneously (without the ressetting "function")

I have also tried the library "ListLib.h". When I use the Clear() function of this library, I get no messages after the first 2 lines. (hangs up?)

mh ok... if i use btDiscover() only (without arrays and so), it works as expected. but if i add my requestData() inside of btDiscover(), i get only once message from each client... idk

ok maybe discover and connect/disconnect dont work together?

mh when i use addDeviceName(deviceName.c_str()) with a variable, i get only one time the messages of clients. if replace the variable with a String, then it works as expected.

Comment: for now, i have moved the discover part to setup() and every 30minutes the esp is restarted... it's not the best approach, but it works... conclusion: discover and connect do not work together

Comment: Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". -- This sounds like a memory overflow problem. _What_ exception is unhandled? Doesn't the ESP tell you more? Are you sure your memory management is correct? (I do not look through code without knowing the exact error message.) -- Please [edit] your question if you have new information, do _not_ post comments. This is not a forum.

Comment: Hi @the busybee, sorry for that misguided post...I will do that again. I was a bit stumped and desperate. My troubleshooting started with the memory overflow (I "fixed" it with delay(XXX)) until I finally came to the conclusion that the discover() function is not usable after a connect(). Because of that i moved the discover()-function to setup() and for the moment I restart the ESP32 regularly. Not nice but it works. The memory overload was not the real problem.